# Apache Flink and Apache Doris Integration (not able to switch to Doris catalog)

Tags: apache-flink, apache-doris

Seeking advice on below.

We are conducting a PoC and are in the process of evaluating Flink and Doris integration using the below versions and dependencies.

- Flink-1.18.1
- Doris-2.0.4
- All the dependencies have been added to POM file

Doris is up and running successfully (set up by following Quick Start from official Doris documentation). Able to access FE using - `http://10.0.2.15:8030`

Below is the PoC code snippet (Java maven project) being used to read the CSV file as Flink FileSystem source and insert it into Doris table as a sink

```java
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.CheckpointingMode;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Table;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.java.StreamTableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.types.Row;
import org.apache.flink.table.catalog.*;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.EnvironmentSettings;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment;

public class FlinkDorisIntegration {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.enableCheckpointing(1000);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage("file:///home/user/Documents/app_data/checkpoint/");
    StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);
        
        // Flink FileSystem CSV format source table in default in-memory catalog
        tableEnv.executeSql("create table IF NOT EXISTS `default_catalog`.`default_database`.`fs_src`(station string, txdate string, txtime string, txseq string)" +
                " with (\n" +
                "'connector' = 'filesystem',\n" +
                "'path'      = 'file:///home/user/Documents/app_data/source/',\n" +
                "'format'    = 'csv',\n" +
                "'csv.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true',\n" +
                "'csv.allow-comments' = 'true',\n" +
                "'source.monitor-interval' = '1s'\n" +
                ");");
                
            // Create Doris Catalog (Not able to execute this, throwing an exception as illegalargumentexception )
        tableEnv.executeSql("CREATE CATALOG demo_catalog WITH('type' = 'jdbc', 'default-database' = 'db_test', 'username' = 'root', 'password' = '', 'base-url' = 'jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.15:9030')");
         
            // Switch to Doris Catalog
        tableEnv.executeSql("USE CATALOG demo_catalog;");
        
        //Create Doris Sink table
        tableEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_test.flink_doris_sink (station varchar, txdate varchar, txtime varchar, txseq varchar) " +
                " with (\n" +
                "'connector' = 'doris',\n" +
                "'fenodes'      = '10.0.2.15:8030',\n" +
                "'table.identifier'    = 'db_test.flink_doris_sink',\n" +
                "'username' = 'root',\n" +
                "'password' = '',\n" +
                "'sink.label-prefix' = 'doris_label'\n" +
                ");");
                
        // Insert into Doris table
        tableEnv.executeSql("INSERT INTO demo_catalog.db_test.flink_doris_sink " +
                " (station, txdate, txtime, txseq)" +
                " SELECT " +
                " station, txdate, txtime, txseq " +
                " FROM `default_catalog`.`default_database`.fs_src; ");

        env.execute();
    }
}
```

To access Doris table, I need to switch to Doris catalog but getting `illegalargumentexception` exception while trying to create Doris catalog from Flink. Running code from Intellij Idea and not as a job by submitting a jar to Flink cluster.

**Can someone please help with the below:**

- Is the approach used in the code snippet the right way to access Doris (create catalog, tables and insert)?
- How to create Doris catalog/table from Flink and access it (any sample code or documentation would be helpful)
- Any prerequisites have been missed?

Comment: As far as I know, you can use Flink with tables in Doris, but there's no support for using a Doris catalog. There are examples in the Doris documentation: https://doris.apache.org/docs/dev/ecosystem/flink-doris-connector/

Comment: @DavidAnderson - I am able to insert data into Doris using Flink DataStream API, but it is just Table API having trouble.

Comment: Take out everything related to the catalog -- rely instead on the built-in, in-memory catalog. The rest should work.